# Disable tooltip "Please fill out this field" when not using <form> tag (DNN)

Tags: angularjs, dotnetnuke

**Setting 'novalidate' or 'formnovalidate' will NOT fix this issue**

I'm using the framework DNN. This framework wraps each page in a form tag which breaks my custom forms. To get passed this I'm using ng-form on a  tag. Because of this fix I always see the default tooltip even though I'm using bootstraps uib-tooltip. I'm willing to go as far as jQuery to fix this issue however I read a post where apparently Chrome and Firefox have both disabled the ability to select and edit the default tooltips. Example:

```
<div role="form" ng-form="myForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <input type="text" id="Identifier" name="Identifier" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="14" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.Identifier" ng-required="true" uib-tooltip="{{ $ctrl.tooltips.identifier }}" tooltip-enable="myForm.Identifier.$invalid && myForm.Identifier.$touched">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Displays "Please fill out this field". How can I remove the default tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2901251) post by jscher2000 I was able to find a work around. Simply add a 'title' tag and set it's contents to an empty space. Simply passing in empty quotes doesn't work there must be at least 1 space between the quotes that's empty. Example:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" title=" ">
```

Thanks.